# how to bypass or edit timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

i found a website and they use this code to hide picture

```
$(function() {
    $('.play_timer').hide();
    var countDownDate = 1590392954000;
    if(countDownDate === 0 || countDownDate === "0"){
        countDownDate = new Date().getTime();
    }
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds + "s  left to see picture!";
        if (distance < 0) {

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "";
            $('.play_timer').show();
        }else{
            $('.play_timer').hide();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

my problem is there any javascript code that can i paste in chrome console so i would not wait 30 sec to view each picture

Comment: `$('.play_timer').show();`?

Comment: @ElanHamburger hamburger when i use that code the picture show and hide again and continue the countdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this (i.e. persist modified JavaScript code) using [Chrome's Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides).